# Cannot leave domain - specified domain does not exist or cannot be contacted

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller

I have a Windows Server instance joined to a domain.

I need to join it to a Workgroup temporarily but when I try to leave the domain it gives me the below error

`"The specified domain either does not exist or cannot be contacted"`

and refuses to join the Workgroup

Any ideas why this could be happening? Strange that I was able to join it just earlier today but now cannot leave it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be DNS.  Can you ping the domain or the domain controllers in that domain?  Although, it could also be a loss of network connectivity.

Comment: Loss of network connectivity was the issue. Thanks, will accept soon